# Calling a web service in JQuery and assign returned Json to JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

This is my first time attempting working with JQuery, Json AND calling a web service.. So please bear with me here.

I need to call a webserivce using JQuery, that then returns a Json object that I then want to save to a javascript variable. I've attempted writing a little something. I just need someone to confirm that this is indeed how you do it. Before I instantiate it and potentially mess up something on my company's servers. Anyways, here it is:

```
var returnedJson = $.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: 'http://172.16.2.45:8080/Auth/login?n=dean&p=hello'
});
```

So there it is, calling a webservice with JQuery and assigning the returned jsonObject to a javascript variable. Can anyone confirm this is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var returnedJson = $.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: 'http://172.16.2.45:8080/Auth/login?n=dean&p=hello'
});
```

If you do it like this `returnedJson` would be an XHR object, and not the json that youre after. You want to handle it in the success callback. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // GET is the default type, no need to specify it
    url: 'http://172.16.2.45:8080/Auth/login',
    data: { n: 'dean', p: 'hello' },
    success: function(data) {
         //data is the object that youre after, handle it here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is crystal clear now. Just want to make sure. In your answer where you commented out '//data is the object that...' if I replace that with returnedJson = data; then it will assign the json object to my global javascript variable. Without ofcourse saying 'var returnedJson = $.ajax(.....' in the beginning of the statement. Correct?

Comment: @DeanGrobler No problem. A common misstake is to declare a variable outside of the success handler and try to assign it inside the function. Since its an asynchronous request, you cant do that. TLDR: use the data/json-object inside the success handler.

Comment: hmmm I see... Lets say for instance I'm a very naive person and I really really wan't to get that JSON object out of that $.ajax statement/function and store it in a JS variable in the document. Is there anyway whatsoever to do this?

Comment: @DeanGrobler Instead of a long story in the comment box, please have a  look here :) http://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+ajax+success+variable+outside+function

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone confirm this is correct?

It will depend on which domain you stored this script. Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built into browsers you cannot send cross domain AJAX requests. This means that if the page serving this script is not hosted on `http://172.16.2.45:8080` this query won't work. The best way to ensure that you are not violating this policy is to use relative urls:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: '/Auth/login?n=dean&p=hello'
});
```

There are several workarounds to the same origin policy restriction but might require you modifying the service that you are trying to consume. Here's a [nice guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) which covers some of the possible workarounds if you need to perform cross domain AJAX calls.

Also there's another issue with your code. You have assigned the result of the `$.ajax` call to some `returnedJson` variable. But that's not how AJAX works. AJAX is asynchronous. This means that the `$.ajax` function will return immediately while the request continues to be executed in the background. Once the server has finished processing the request and returned a response the results will be available in the `success` callback that you need to subscribe to and which will be automatically invoked:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: '/Auth/login?n=dean&p=hello',
    success: function(returnedJson) {
        // use returnedJson here
    }
});
```

And yet another remark about your code: it seems that you are calling a web service that performs authentication and sending a username and password. To avoid transmitting this information in clear text over the wire it is highly recommended to use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) does not return the data, it returns a [jQuery jqHXR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

You need to use the success callback to handle the data, and also deal with the same origin policy as Darin mentions.